# MongoDB + Node - 2x insert vs insert and update performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-performance

I am developing an app in node.js to register the entry and the exit of users
in a given website page. So I came across two options for this:

1 - Create one register for entry and another for exit in my collection

2 - Insert a document on entry and update this document with the exit properties (e.g. time)

I made some tests and I was a little surprise to see that inserting 2 documents
in my MongoDB was faster than inserting and updating only one (I am finding the
document by its _id)

Is this behavior expected? Thanks

Comment: Of course? It's 3 operations (put, get, put) vs 2 operations (put, put)

Comment: How are you performing the update? Code example would be best

Comment: EkoostikMartin: I measure the error of the whole operation and, as I am sending much less information from the client in case 2 I was hoping that it will be quicker.

Comment: Code example would indeed be good. Does your update change existing fields, add new ones, ... ?

Comment: @G.Führ could u please explain what test you ran? I am in need of some similar tests.